# Backend: Entry list failes to load

Tags: entries, admin

I use Craft Pro CMS 3.7.39 [edit: now updated to  Craft Pro CMS 3.7.42] in headless mode. Worked fine for some weeks now - but without configuration or code change some of many sections entry lists failes to load. The loading spinner keeps spinning - after ~1 minute a empty entry list is loaded. There are ~ 3000 entries in the database.

[image: empty entry list is loaded]

Nginx, PHP-FPM and MySQL logs are clean. :(

[image: System Info]

any ideas how to figure out thats going on?

### edit 1

there is a little error banner:
[image: a server error occoured]

### edit 2

in the browser log there is one XHR Request, that dosnt return - i think thats the error:

[image]

### edit 3

graphql is successfully able to query the sections that do not work in the admin gui. so the database part cloud be okay.

### edit 4

this is the .env file

```
# The environment Craft is currently running in (dev, staging, production, etc.)
ENVIRONMENT=dev

# The application ID used to to uniquely store session and cache data, mutex locks, and more
APP_ID=XXXXX

# The secure key Craft will use for hashing and encrypting data
SECURITY_KEY=XXXX

# Database Configuration
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_SERVER=XXXX
DB_PORT=XXXX
DB_DATABASE=XXXX
DB_USER=XXXX
DB_PASSWORD=XXXX
DB_SCHEMA=XXXX
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=XXXX

CRAFT_CMS_URL=https://craft.xxxxx.de
CRAFT_CMS_ROOT=/srv/www/xxxxx_craft/web
```

this is the general.php

```
<?php
/**
 * General Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's general configuration settings go in here. You can see a
 * list of the available settings in vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/GeneralConfig.php.
 *
 * @see \craft\config\GeneralConfig
 */

use craft\helpers\App;

$isDev = App::env('ENVIRONMENT') === 'dev';
$isProd = App::env('ENVIRONMENT') === 'production';

return [
    // Default Week Start Day (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday...)
    'defaultWeekStartDay' => 1,

    // Whether generated URLs should omit "index.php"
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,

    // The URI segment that tells Craft to load the control panel
    'baseCpUrl' =>  null,
    'cpTrigger' => 'admin',

    // The secure key Craft will use for hashing and encrypting data
    'securityKey' => App::env('SECURITY_KEY'),

    // Whether Dev Mode should be enabled (see https://craftcms.com/guides/what-dev-mode-does)
    'devMode' => $isDev,

    // Whether administrative changes should be allowed
    'allowAdminChanges' => $isDev,

    // Whether crawlers should be allowed to index pages and following links
    'disallowRobots' => !$isProd,

    // Whether the system should run in Headless Mode, which optimizes the system and control panel for headless CMS implementations.
    'headlessMode' => true,
    'limitAutoSlugsToAscii' => true,

    // Whether the EXIF data should be preserved when manipulating and uploading images.
    'preserveExifData' => true,
//    'defaultDirMode' => '2775',

    'aliases' => [
        '@web' => App::env('CRAFT_CMS_URL') ? App::env('CRAFT_CMS_URL') : null,
        '@webroot' => App::env('CRAFT_CMS_ROOT') ? App::env('CRAFT_CMS_ROOT') : null,
    ]
];
```

## edit 5

both site configurations:

[image: both site configurations]

## edit 6

section configuration:
[image: section configuration]

## edit 7

here you see the console output in the error case
[image: error case]

here you see the console output in the no error case
[image: no error case]

XHR the index.php?admin/actions/.../get-elements/ fail to return ANY value.

## edit 8

- there are no relevant errors in web.log.

[image: web.log]

- there are no relevant errors in /storage/logs/phperrors.log
- there are no relevant errors in /var/log/php7.3-fpm.log
- there are no relevant errors in /var/log/nginx/XXXXX_craft.error.log
- there are no relevant errors in /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: Not in all cases an empty list is loaded. If i open a other entry view before the faulty one - the previous list stays

Comment: Hey Merkur, how is your config (env & general.php)? Whats the url and what did you set as siteUrl? Did you set the url of the backend? Maybe https issues? Is there any output in the console?

Comment: Hello Max, I added .env and general.php to the post. nothing crazy there I belive. I use Craft CMS in headless mode only - the section urls are just defined by the entry id. there are 2 sites a german and a english variation they are configured as sub directories of the the craft cms url  @web

Comment: Updated to Version Craft Pro CMS 3.7.42 - nothing changed :(

Comment: I just discoverd that the entries overview of the secound site - the english version works. I updated the post with screen shots of the site configuration. I also configured a fixed @web and increased the php max_execution_time to 120 - still no joy

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your browsers console (in the chrome dev tools)? Maybe there's a hint where the javascript has problems

Comment: i added screen shots of the error and no error case as edit 7. as you see the XHR get-elements dont return a value / error

Comment: is there some kind of database consistency check utility for craft cms?

Comment: You could have a look at the console commands. They hav utilities to repair structures. But I guess there's rather something wrong with your site setup, if one shows and the other does not. You might also want to check out the discord. Did you try to query the url directly?

Comment: I toke another look at the log files - see edit 8, no joy :/

Comment: Hello Max, thank you for your time and questions. I'll try to get help from the developers.

Comment: Hello, i solved the problem. The reason CrafCMS did no log any error, is that there is no craft error. :) The SSL Connection is blocked by some combination effect btween Firefox and the AntiVir System. Without AntiVir Software or in Chrome it runs great.

Comment: @Merkur Can you add that as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The reason CrafCMS did not log any error, is that there is no craft error. :) The SSL Certificate to the XHR was blocked by some combination effect between Firefox and the AntiVir System. Without AntiVir Software or in Chrome it runs great.

The error message "a server error occured" was missleading, because it was a client connection error.

thank you for your help / Merkur